# System.IO.Path.GetExtension returns null in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I have a **fileupload** in my page so the user can browse the computer and select the file. After selecting the file when I want to get the name of file using this code:

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

It returns null and I got this error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

After debugging I found that my file is posted null and it doesn't send. Why? After adding a little code I got this error :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
<div class="wrapper-box">
                                <div class="topbox">
                                    عکس خبر
                                </div>
                                 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="text-input-two" />
                            </div>


        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: check if FileUpload1.PostedFile is null or not.

Comment: How can it return null AND throw an exception? Please be more specific: which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName); this line Throws an exception

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Try to check if FileUpload1.PostedFile is null, sometimes the asp:FileUpload component don't work with update panel

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN GetExtension will only return null if you pass in a FileName that's null.

> The extension of the specified path (including the period "."), or
>   Nothing[Null], or String.Empty. If path is Nothing[Null], GetExtension
>   returns Nothing[Null]. If path does not have extension information,
>   GetExtension returns String.Empty.

So check if **(file != null && file.FileName != null)** first before proceeding furthure.

Answer (score 1):

Get extension method returns a extension of file. 
check following code sample

```
string s = System.IO.Path.GetExtension("file1.aspx");
```

you can use 
**FileUpload1.fileName** instead of **fileupload1.postedfile.filename**

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this postback trigger between  and

```
</ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension("FileName.ext");
```

Instead of

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```